# Vertical alignment (centering) of cells contents in longtable with "m"

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table which cells can have one or more lines of text. I want to center all cell contents vertically, while horizontally making text left aligned. So far I have come up with this code:

```
\documentclass[final,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % needed for "m" in longtable
\usepackage[paperwidth=9in,paperheight=3in,right=0.5in,bottom=0in,left=0.2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent\begin{longtable}{@{} m{.30\paperwidth} m{.30\paperwidth} m{.30\paperwidth}@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
\textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3}
\\\addlinespace
\toprule\endhead
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r1) & This is second column (c2, r1), line one\newline This is second column (c2, r1), line two & This is third column (c3, r1), line one\newline This is third column (c3, r1), line two
\\\addlinespace\hline
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r2) & This is second column (c2, r2), line one\newline This is second column (c2, r2), line two & This is third column (c3, r2), line one\newline This is third column (c3, r2), line two
\\\addlinespace\hline
3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r3) & c2, r3 & c3, r3
\\\addlinespace\hline
4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r4) & c2, r4, line one \newline c2, r4, line two & c3, r4, line one\newline c3, r4, line two
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
All text in the cells should be centered vertically and left aligned horizontally.
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Only header row contents is properly centered vertically. All other cells are not centered vertically and they differ in how much padding is at the top of the cell.

Why are those cells not centered as intended? Isn't it what `m` (from `array` package) in longtable definition is supposed to do? How can I make sure that text in each cell is centered vertically, regardless of how many lines of text is in it?

Comment: your image shows you are getting vertical alignment in all cells. Draw a line through the vertical centre of each entry and you'll see they line up. (`m` is nothing to do with the space above and below the row it  is about the alignment of entries with other entries in the same row.

Comment: The reason you have more space below the single line entries than above is that you added extra space with  `\addlinespace`

Comment: Instead of `\addlinespace\hline`, use `\midrule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually inserting `\addlinespace` directives in lots of places, you may want to increase the values of `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` via `\addtolength` instructions. Separately, do consider using `\midrule` instead of `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\addtolength\aboverulesep{0.15ex}  % extra spacing above and below rules
\addtolength\belowrulesep{0.35ex}

\usepackage{longtable, array} % "array" is needed for "m" in longtable

\usepackage[paperwidth=9in,paperheight=3in,right=0.5in,bottom=0in,left=0.2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{longtable}{@{} *{3}{m{.30\paperwidth}} @{}}

\toprule
\textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] % make this rule as thick as \toprule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r1) & This is second column (c2, r1), line one\newline This is second column (c2, r1), line two & This is third column (c3, r1), line one\newline This is third column (c3, r1), line two \\
\midrule
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r2) & This is second column (c2, r2), line one\newline This is second column (c2, r2), line two & This is third column (c3, r2), line one\newline This is third column (c3, r2), line two \\
\midrule
3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r3) & c2, r3 & c3, r3 \\
\midrule
4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (c1, r4) & c2, r4, line one \newline c2, r4, line two & c3, r4, line one\newline c3, r4, line two \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is advantage of using ``\midrule`` over ``\hline``?

Comment: @Rafal - `\midrule` automatically inserts whitespace -- in the amounts of `\aboverulsep` and `\belowrulesep`, resp. -- above and below the rule, whereas `\hline` does not.

Comment: That's a nice solution but (1) now I have white spaces if I use \rowcolor{} and (2) vertical lines do not connect ... there are white spaces in-between too. Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: @Jonas - My answer does not feature any vertical lines (by design!), and it also doesn't feature any `\rowcolor` directives. I'm afraid my psychic abilities are utterly worthless, and my divination skills are equally poor. My deepest apologies. Try though I might, I simply have no idea how your code differs from mine, let alone what your ultimate typesetting objectives may be. Hence, I'm unable to make any constructive suggestions regarding your code. Very sorry.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454336/longtable-custom-column-width-and-no-white-spaces-between-lines :)

Comment: I have vertical separator lines, and `\midrule` breaks them

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - Please feel free to read the very well written user guide of the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package. There, you'll find a clear statement that the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package should *never* be used if table has vertical rules. Conversely, if you do wish to employ the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, *don't use vertical rules*. It's as simple as that. By the way, I assume you've noticed that the table posted in my answer does *not* contain vertical rules. That's not an accident, but a deliberate choice.

Comment: Hmmm I need some effort to adapt to the idea. My opinion is that one has to provide the reader the possibility to concentrate on the essence, without distractions to any irrelevant additional mindwork needed to separate columns from each other...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - What "additional mindwork needed to separate columns from each other"? Whitespace can be every bit as good at providing a visual separator as a solid black line does. Virtually all visual design professionals recommend *against* using vertical rules in tables, because vertical rules excel at creating a "prison cell window with bars" look, which discourages the eye from roaming around the table and taking in its contents as a whole. Do please take the time to read the user guide of the `booktabs` package, which contains an excellent discussion of just these matters.

Comment: Well I think it still depends on content. Actually the reason I reacted is that right now I am slowly building a huge several pages table with one of the columns holding certain Dynkin-like graphs of varying forms, and I believe it would definitely ease reading the table if they would be confined to rectangular frames.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - Well, *you* started this thread, by commenting on a several-years-old answer of mine which features a table that has absolutely no need for vertical rules. If you had wanted to steer the conversation toward an unusual use case which, if I understood you correctly, appears to have nothing in common with the vast majority of all tables, it would have been up to you to do so early on. Instead, we mainly appear to have succeeded in wasting each others' time. I do apologize, though, for having no idea what a "Dynkin-like graph" might look like...

Comment: I just wanted to provide additional piece of information that might be useful for an occasional user like me. I would benefit from this, so I thought somebody else could benefit from it too. What I am doing is not that unique after all, I have seen several such tables before...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - Your first comment was, "I have vertical separator lines, and `\midrule` breaks them". As you explained subsequently, it is very important to you to have vertical separator lines in your table. The only sensible conclusion, then, is that using `\midrule` is not the way to go *for your table*. Naturally, what may be sensible for your table, *viz.*, employing vertical separator lines, need not to be sensible for other tables.

Comment: I completely agree with every word of your last comment.